# eclipse text formatter

Tags: eclipse

I have written some code in eclipse which has a lot of blank lines.
I need to format the code and remove the blank lines.
How do I go about this?

Answer (score 6):

You can use the default text formatter by selecting the code you want to format and then typing:

**Ctrl + Shift + F** (Contextual menu Source -> Format)

If this doesn't work you can edit this default formatter by changing the Existing blank lines - Number of empty lines to preserve from 1 to your number in Prefrences Java Code Style Formatter Edit Eclipse default formater Blank line tab.

Comment: Well Ctrl+Shift+F is inconsistent, how to test: Use Ctrl+Shift+F, save and commit to your source control. Add some code lines. Repeat previous steps and you'll see that the whole code formatting has changed ... Arrr....

Comment: You can enable a save action so your source is reformatted every time you save.  Very convenient.